# forwarding message between clients with a server in middle

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor

I want to take a message from one client and send it to the other with a server in middle.
I use the `select` function to make several connections to the server possible but here is the problem:
I store the socket descriptor `sock` in `Queue[pq]` using `dup` and it's working. the `sock = 4 & Queue[0] = 5`. now I need to take the other client's socket descriptor, and again I store it in `Queue`. the values of `Queue` for Client(2) equals to `Queue[0] = 5 , Queue[1] = 7` but for the first client it's still `Queue[0] = 5 and Queue[1] = 0` it means the code for first client doesn't have access to the second client's socket descriptor and i cant forward it to the other client using his socket descriptor with `send()` and client 3 has the the first 2 client's socket descriptor but the first 2 client doesn't have the third one's socket descriptor.
I think that's because `select()` use different memory address for the values for each client just like `sock` which has different values for each connection.
how I can solve this problem? how the clients can access each other's socket descriptor?
the code:

```
Global Values:
int tcpfd, udpfd, Sock, nready, maxfdp1;
int Queue[64];
int pq = -1;

int max(int x, int y) {
    if (x > y) 
        return x; 
    else
        return y; 
}

int main(){
pid_t childpid;
fd_set rset;
ssize_t n;
socklen_t len;
const int on = 1;
struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
void sig_chld(int);

/* create listening TCP socket */
tcpfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.5");
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

// binding server addr structure to tcpfd 
bind(tcpfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 
listen(tcpfd, 10);

// clear the descriptor set 

// get maxfd 
maxfdp1 = max(tcpfd, udpfd) + 1;
for (;;) {
    // set tcpfd and udpfd in readset
    FD_ZERO(&rset); 
    FD_SET(tcpfd, &rset); 

    // select the ready descriptor 
    nready = select(maxfdp1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL); 

    // if tcp socket is readable then handle 
    // it by accepting the connection
    if (FD_ISSET(tcpfd, &rset)){
        len = sizeof(cliaddr); 
        Sock = accept(tcpfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &len);
        pq++;
        Queue[pq] = dup(Sock);
        printf("%d\n",Sock);
        if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) {
            Access_Request();
            while(1) { //rest of the code
              }
```

Comment: The `sock` descriptors are file descriptors. They are only meaningful for a given process. So, if clients A and B connect to server S, A will have an fd for communication with S [and likewise for B]. S will get _two_ fds. There is _no_ relationship between any of these. For example, A will get 3, B will get 3, and S will get 5 for A and 6 for B. So, sending 6 to A and 5 to B is meaningless. A must send to S, marking the message for B. Then, S must forward/send the message to B [or vice versa]. The actual `sock` numbers are irrelevant. If A could learn of 5 it can't send to B directly with that

Comment: Let's assume A connects to S. _Later_, B connects to S. How does A learn of B's existence? You'd need to devise a protocol. (e.g.) `A: query client list IDs` and then: `S: A=0, B=1` Then, A can do: `A: sendto=1,msg='hello world'`. And, B can do a similar query and, then, to send to A can do: `B: sendto=0,msg='goodbye universe'`. The ID numbers are just monotonically increasing numbers assigned by S (i.e. they are _not_ fds).

Comment: @CraigEstey thanks for the comment I'll work on your solution. thanks for helping.